# When is an Object created after a constructor is called

Tags: java, object, constructor, creation

Consider the following code classes.

```
     public class A
    {
        public A()
        {
            callCreation();
        }

        protected void callCreation()
        {
            System.out.println("A Created!!");
        }
    }




    public class B extends A
    {
        protected void callCreation()
        {
            System.out.println("B Created!!");
        }
    }


    public class C extends B
    {
        protected void callCreation()
        {
            System.out.println("C Created!!");
        }

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            A a = new A();
            A b = new B();
            A c = new C();
        }
    }
```

The output of running the class C is given below.

```
A Created!!
B Created!!
C Created!!
```

The first output line in the output

```
A Created!!
```

is printed because when the constructor of class A is called, it calls the super class's constructor (java.lang.Object) implicitly before calling the callCreation() method in the class A's constructor. And this will be the case for B and C classes too. In that case when the constructor of B is called the call flow should be typically : B's constructor -> A's Constructor -> java.lang.Object's Constructor -> come back to A's callCreation() method to finish calling A's constructor. If so how is the overridden value printed and not the super class's value is printed? So the question is 'when is an object of a class created exactly? to put it in other words, the object of a class should be created only after the constructor finishes calling/initializing all the elements within itself. If so how can a method be called from a child class and not from the parent class?

Answer (score 4):

The `callCreation` methods in B and C **override** the method from A. So when the method is called in the constructor A the implementations in B and C will be run, even though the constructors of B and C have not been executed yet. This is possible because constructors don't actually create the object, rather they are called to *initialize* some moments after the JVM has created it.

In general it's a very bad idea to call methods that can be overridden from a constructor for this very reason. A method in B or C may assume that the constructor and object initializers have already been run, and read an unexpected value from a field. For example the following ends up printing `"B Created!! null"` because the field still has not be assigned its value.

```
public class B extends A
{
    final String msg = "Yes!";

    protected void callCreation()
    {
        System.out.println("B Created!! "+msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 Exactly - it's always being called from the same constructor. The only difference is where the call goes.

Comment: Doesnt the jvm need an object to call a method on it? Please find my comment in the answer below.

Comment: Yes; in fact it also needs an object on which to *run the constructor*. The object exists long before the constructor gets executed.

Comment: I am a little confused here. How can an object exist before it is constructed?

Comment: The term "constructor" is misleading. Really they are just special methods that are called shortly after the JVM has created object.

Comment: @user1223879 - Joni's right. A good example is the usage of `this` in constructors; by the time a constructor's called you already have an object in memory to refer to. That's why "leaking" references to `this` before a constructor is finished [can be problematic](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8234695/697449).

Comment: Thanks for your comments and ideas Joni & Paul. Now I got an overview of what happens when a constructor is called. Though I knew the way it works I wanted to know why it works that way and got it :) Thanks for your inputs...

Answer (score 1):

thinking in this way makes it more obvious:
when an object of type B is being created super() keyword calls the A constructor, 
then in A constructor "this.callCreation()" is executed, which refers to the current
object which is B, so callCreation corresponding to the current object(B) is called.
the same process is done for C.

public class A {

```
public A() {
    this.callCreation();
}

protected void callCreation() {
    System.out.println("A Created!!");
}
```

}

class B extends A {

```
public B() {
    super();
}

protected void callCreation() {
    System.out.println("B Created!!");
}
```

}

class C extends B {

```
public C() {
    super();
}

protected void callCreation() {
    System.out.println("C Created!!");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

       A a = new A();
       A b = new B();
       A c = new C();

}
```

}