# Why constructors are called on the time of Object Creation?

Tags: java, constructor

According to [this](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/General/JavaSyntax/constructors.html), Constructors are actually initializer. And according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9381959/when-is-an-object-created-after-a-constructor-is-called/9381992#9381992) answer object is already created before the constructor after the `new` keyword is called.

So my Question is What is the need of putting constructor after a `new` keyword if i do not want to initialize anything.

Comment: Why don't you want to initialize your object?

Comment: If you don't want to do anything when the object is created, you can have an empty constructor. Is there a good reason you want an initialised object? (BTW You can do this, but I suspect this is not really what you want)

Comment: @codemaker: do any of the answers address your question?  If not, can you clarify your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think of it like this...

1. The JVM allocates memory for the object, but it has not been initialized or wired up.
2. The JVM assigns common stuff for the object in memory, like pointers to methods, static variables, etc.  While the object exists, it's still not uniquely initialized by executing the constructor.
3. The constructor is called, which initializes the object.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to initialize your variable, you can just declare it:

```
MyObject myObject;
```

However, if you want to be able to do anything at all with `myObject`, you need to create an object that the variable can point to, and that is done with the `new` keyword. Otherwise `myObject` is just pointing to a big nothing.

Comment: That doesn't really declare an object.  It declares a variable that will eventually "contain" or "point to" an object of the specified type.

Comment: @atk: I didn't say declare an object, I said declare a variable.

Comment: You are correct in that.  I expected that this would confuse the OP, as I thought they were really confused about the difference between when the object is allocated and when it's initialized, so added clarification.  Apologies for not being clearer in my intention :)

Answer (score 1):

Over the years, the terminology in Java's upstream languages intrudes on the Java language.

In the past (C) allocation was a separate step from initialization.  They combined in C++, and now are considered the same thing.  Technically, the order of operations in "construction" is

1. Allocated memory for the object
2. Initialize that memory as specified.

These steps may be done multiple times for parent classes of the object.  The key is that allocation always precedes initialization, and the two are tightly coupled.  Allocation must precede initialization, or the initialization has no memory to initialize.  Constructors guarantee both are done to avoid earlier issues in other languages where programs would access random data by accessing allocated but not initialized items.  Constructors were created to protect against such bugs.

Now, the stuff you assign to is a variable, and variables hold references to values (in Java, for objects).  So you can consider a variable simply a name that can be dereferenced to a value.  If you want a new name, but want to have it reference nothing, then Keppil's answer is best.

MyType myName;

which will create a name with a reference to no value (null).

However, in Java, object values *must* be initialized.  There is no "allocate without initialization", as this would be the equivalent to having an object with random internal state.  Random internal state means that using the object would have (at best) random results, and (at worst) references to objects that didn't exist.  With the tight coupling in construction of allocation and initalization, the type system works; without it, you could theoretically have a reference to an object that doesn't exist, recreating the segmentation fault of C in Java.

Comment: :`MyType myName` references to `null`, so how `MyType myName=new MyType()` will initialize the Object if `MyType()` is a default constructor?

Comment: The `new MyType()` is a combined set of commands to allocate the necessary memory, initialize that memory according to the constructor instructions, and return a reference.  The `MyType myName` part is just a reference (like a pointer), it doesn't have any memory beyond the amount to hold a reference, and the whole operation `MyType myName = new MyType()` constructs the object on the right, and then assigns the returned reference into the memory location "named" on the left.  It's not C++, so you can never make an object without the `new` keyword (no in-place allocation).

Comment: As far as the default constructor, basically all objects come with one constructor _if an only if you don't declare one_.  If you don't declare a constructor, the compiler adds in `public MyType() { super(); }` as the constructor.  If you declare a constructor, then no default constructor exists.  In either case, `new (insert constructor here)` never calls a constructor beyond the one you insert, so the only "default" part about constructors doesn't impact the `new MyType()` part (because it's explicitly declared, so not default).

Answer (score 0):

You want to initialize the object itself, which includes allocating memory for the object.  There's other housekeeping internals that need to be done as well.

Answer (score 0):

To quote the link you posted:

> The job of the constructor is to ensure that the new object is in a valid state ...

Do you really want to create an object and not have it in a valid state?

If you however just want an object reference, just declare one and do not call new.

```
MyClass mc;
```

Comment: what do you mean by `valid state`?

Answer (score 0):

You are right, Java syntax could be

```
String str = new
```

instead of

```
String str = new String()
```

to give you an empty string.  The problem is sometimes we want to pass parameters into a constructor like this:

```
String str = new String("text")
```

which is why we call the constructor.  To keep the syntax consistent, you have to also call default constructors `String()`.  In this case `String` is an immutable class so there is no other way to set it's initial value.

Comment: You can also do `List list = new ArrayList()`. In your example `List list = new` would be ambiguous.

Comment: Good point, I think this is what he was asking for, not sure why the top answers are up there...